# Is there a way to access webmin using APIs

Tags: linux, api, cron, webmin

I have installed webmin on my centos linux server.

I want to set a cron or list cron jobs using API which I can call through any python or php code.
I tried finding any such thing on internet and in webmin documentation, but couldnt find anything.

Has anyone tried this or knows how this thing can be implemented ?

I know I can create a PHP api or python api , which in turn can run shell commands to add crontab, but I am looking native-webmin API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/XML-RPC_Calls documents a way to perform rpc calls. You can, for example, execute such a call using `curl` with

```
 curl --data @testcall -k https://root:changeme@192.168.0.100:10000/xmlrpc.cgi
```

where the content of `testcall` is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <methodCall>
 <methodName>useradmin::list_users</methodName>
 <params>
 <param>
 <value>apiUser</value>
 </param>
 <param>
 <value>apiKey</value>
 </param>
 </params>
 </methodCall>
```